# 2to3py (Does it exist?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, compatibility, python-2.x

I know of the program 3to2, which converts python 3 to python 2, but lets say I wanted to convert 2 to 3? Is that possible? Or do I have to do it by hand

Comment: [Google really did not help?](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=python+2to3)

Comment: Google for "porting to python 3"

Comment: Even though this can easily be googled or looked up in the Python docs, it's still a valid question. I don't get the downvotes. Keep it at 0 (for no research) and all is well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html